# How do I insert data into a table containg struct data type in BQ

Tags: google-bigquery

While trying to insert data into the following table, I get the following error message.

```
--create table mydataset.struct_1(x struct<course string,id int64>)
insert into `mydataset.struct_1` (course,id)  values("B.A",12)

Error: Column course is not present in table mydataset.struct_1 at [2:35]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
-- CREATE TABLE mydataset.struct_1(x STRUCT<course STRING,id INT64>)
INSERT INTO `mydataset.struct_1` (x)  VALUES(STRUCT("B.A",12))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create STRUCT with a nested STRUCT named x with two fields y and z you should do [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#struct-type):

```
STRUCT<x STRUCT<y INT64, z INT64>>
```

So in your example:

```
create table mydataset.struct_1(STRUCT<x STRUCT<course string,id int64>>)
```

Comment: I am not creating struct within a nested struct.  I just need a struct with two fileds in create table DDL statement, and how do I insert data into it?

Comment: in that case Mikhail right u have to x STRUCT<y STRING, z INT64>>

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE STRUCT_1 (x STRUCT<course: STRING,id: int>)
comment 'demonstrating how to work-around to insert complex 
datatype unnested structs into a complex table '
Stored as parquet
location '/user/me/mestruct'
tblproperties ('created date: '=' 2019/01','done by: '='me');
```

Now lets do the insert.

```
insert into table STRUCT_1 select named_struct("course","B.A","id",12) from (select 't') s;
```